# How to assure that screen designed using html5 supports all possible device sizes (Landscape and Portrait)

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I am using html5 to design mobile device screens to create platform independent application.
I am using media queries for the same reason but these media queries support some mentioned devices like iphone4, ipad, ipad mini, samsung devices.
What is the assured thing that irrespective of any device size/resolution the page will fit perfectly on any device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how and why are your media queries are that specific, that they only cover the mentioned devices.

A better approach is to use ranged media query, e.g. taken from bootstrap:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```